# Page item not being persistent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, persistence

In my ASP.NET page, I have a generic class that is defined as below:

```
public partial class log_states : BasePage
{
    protected class StatesUsed
    {
        public int StateCode { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }
    private List<StatesUsed> _statesUsed;
}
```

In the Page_Load() event, I initialize `_statesUsed` like below, and bind it to a grid:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        _statesUsed = new List<StatesUsed>();
        BindMyGrid();
    }
}

private void BindMyGrid()
{
    gvStates.DataSource = _statesUsed;
    gvStates.DataBind();
}
```

I then have a form to add new States. When the user adds a state, I'm trying to add it to the local `_statesUsed` variable, and rebind the grid. Example:

```
protected void btnAddState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _statesUsed.Add(new StatesUsed { StateCode = 1, StateName = "Test" });

    BindMyGrid();
}
```

This always fails when trying to add the new item saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"...

How do I keep `_statesUsed` persistant? The idea is to add all user input using the generic class and then update the database at one go. If you know of another way to accomplish this, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
private List<StatesUsed> _statesUsed;
```

I'm usually using something similar to:

```
private List<StatesUsed> _statesUsed
{
    get
    {
        var result = ViewState["_stateUsed"] as List<StatesUsed>;

        if ( result == null )
        {
            result = new List<StatesUsed>();
            ViewState["_stateUsed"] = result;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I.e. I am persisting page class variables to the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx).

Comment: Since the viewstate is a text value, everything that goes into it needs to be serializable, so you would also need to mark the StatesUsed class as [Serializable]

Comment: Thanks Andreas and Uwe! This works beautifully. And yes, it needed the `Serializable` attribute set on the class...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep stuff "alive" through multiple postbacks you either have to store stuff to a database, use Session, use the Viewstate, or store it temporarily in shared server memory. Which of these you choose is dependent on your use case,

In your case I would probably add an asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HiddenFieldUsedStateIDs" in which I wrote the IDs comma separated whenever there is a change and then read the values into the generic list in Page_Load (on *every* Page_Load, not just !IsPostBack)

This would utilize the Viewstate mechanism in Asp.Net to write the values to the rendered HTML and read it back into the HiddenField's value on each post

Answer (score -1):

Asuuming that your viewstate in not disabled, you could do,

```
  protected void btnAddMat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {     
         List<StatesUsed> temp = null;  

        temp =  (List<StatesUsed>)gvStates.DataSource;
        if(temp != null)
          temp.Add(new StatesUsed { StateCode = 1, StateName = "Test" });                    
gvStates.DataBind();           
   }
```

Comment: This does not work as `gvStates.DataSource` is an object and so will fail. Casting doesn't help either.